# Left-align collection view cell without cell width going over content view?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have cells that are added and when I add the cells with larger widths, it goes over. What I want is to wrap over if there isn't enough space to between a cell and the right side of the content view.

Here's what's happening:

[image]

Here are my settings for the collection view:

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: self.tableView.separatorInset.left, bottom: 15, right: self.tableView.separatorInset.left)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 60
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .black
    cv.isScrollEnabled = false
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear

    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.register(TagCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "tagCV")
    return cv
}()
```

I also have the code to left align the cells through the attributes of the cell, which I got from GitHub
(https://github.com/fanpyi/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout-Swift):

```
extension UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    func leftAlignFrameWithSectionInset(_ sectionInset:UIEdgeInsets){
        var frame = self.frame
        frame.origin.x = sectionInset.left
        self.frame = frame
    }
}

class UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var attributesCopy: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    if let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) {
        attributes.forEach({ attributesCopy.append($0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) })
    }

    for attributes in attributesCopy {
        if attributes.representedElementKind == nil {
            let indexpath = attributes.indexPath
            if let attr = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexpath) {
                attributes.frame = attr.frame
            }
        }
    }
    return attributesCopy
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

    if let currentItemAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        let sectionInset = self.evaluatedSectionInsetForItem(at: indexPath.section)
        let isFirstItemInSection = indexPath.item == 0
        let layoutWidth = self.collectionView!.frame.width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right

        if (isFirstItemInSection) {
            currentItemAttributes.leftAlignFrameWithSectionInset(sectionInset)
            return currentItemAttributes
        }

        let previousIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: indexPath.item - 1, section: indexPath.section)

        let previousFrame = layoutAttributesForItem(at: previousIndexPath)?.frame ?? CGRect.zero
        let previousFrameRightPoint = previousFrame.origin.x + previousFrame.width
        let currentFrame = currentItemAttributes.frame
        let strecthedCurrentFrame = CGRect.init(x: sectionInset.left,
                                                y: currentFrame.origin.y,
                                                width: layoutWidth,
                                                height: currentFrame.size.height)
        // if the current frame, once left aligned to the left and stretched to the full collection view
        // widht intersects the previous frame then they are on the same line
        let isFirstItemInRow = !previousFrame.intersects(strecthedCurrentFrame)

        if (isFirstItemInRow) {
            // make sure the first item on a line is left aligned
            currentItemAttributes.leftAlignFrameWithSectionInset(sectionInset)
            return currentItemAttributes
        }

        var frame = currentItemAttributes.frame
        frame.origin.x = previousFrameRightPoint + evaluatedMinimumInteritemSpacing(at: indexPath.section)
        currentItemAttributes.frame = frame
        return currentItemAttributes

    }
    return nil
}

func evaluatedMinimumInteritemSpacing(at sectionIndex:Int) -> CGFloat {
    if let delegate = self.collectionView?.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        let inteitemSpacing = delegate.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt: sectionIndex)
        if let inteitemSpacing = inteitemSpacing {
            return inteitemSpacing
        }
    }
    return self.minimumInteritemSpacing

}

func evaluatedSectionInsetForItem(at index: Int) ->UIEdgeInsets {
    if let delegate = self.collectionView?.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        let insetForSection = delegate.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, insetForSectionAt: index)
        if let insetForSectionAt = insetForSection {
            return insetForSectionAt
        }
    }
    return self.sectionInset
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot be completely sure, but for your section inset, are you sure you want the right inset to also be self.tableView.separatorInset.left ?

Comment: Yes, it gives padding to a cell small enough if it reaches the right end

Comment: have you tried setting the content size of the collection view to the width that you require ?

Comment: Yes. I just set it to the bounds width. Still nothing. Is there a way in which I can fiddle with layoutAttributes and if the cell's width is more than the content size width, i can just change that attribute's frame to the left? Because I tried it and it only moved that very cell down a little but not to the left.